# Is "return eval" evil?

Tags: php, eval

Given the statement

```
$someValue = eval("return \$$userSetting;");
```

How could `$userSetting` be dangerous? It seems the worst it could do is expose variables but that is actually what it's supposed to be doing in this code. Is there some way to execute arbitrary code with PHP's [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)?

Comment: `$userSetting = 'userSetting && (function() { do whatever you want })();'` ?

Comment: eval is never a good option. Someone with no good intentions can simply inject new code to your code. If you need to return a variable "dynamically" you can use the concept of variable of variables, which is basicaly what you're trying to do, but without the evil eval.

Comment: @zerkms In the shell (`php -a`) I'm getting `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in php shell code(1) : eval()'d code on line 1`.

Comment: @jcuenod https://3v4l.org/FDVCE php >= 7 only.

Comment: Even if you don't care about PHP7 you can do something like `&& die(file_get_contents('/etc/passwd'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily invoke an arbitrary function (to be more precise - an arbitrary expression) there:

```
$userSetting = 'userSetting && print(123)';
```

This would work in all (?) php versions.

With php7 it becomes even more convenient since you can call an anonymous function in-place:

```
$userSetting = 'userSetting && (function() { do whatever you want })();';
```